# 'For' iterator in python doesn't return the right answer

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

I wrote this in python to calculate the number of primes under a given value. It prints "0" when I execute the code. Could anyone tell me why my code is going wrong?

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    else:    
        for value in range(2, x):
            if x%value == 0:
                return False
        else: 
            return True

def primes_in(x):
    primes = [ ]
    for value in range(2, x+1):
        if is_prime(value):
            primes.append(1)
        elif not is_prime(value):
            primes.append(0)
        else: 
            primes.append(0)
    return sum(primes)

print primes_in(25)
```

Comment: `range(2, x+1)` makes sure that the `x` is also included in the iteration. So, it will always return `False`.

Comment: Also the pythonic way would be: 

if is_prime(value):
.....
elif not is_prime(value):

Comment: Why two `else` ? ... I think First one is sufficient?

Comment: After the change it prints `9` on my machine.

Comment: BTW, using a list (`primes`) as a counter is rather wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

See [range function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).
`range(start, stop[, step])`

```
 for value in range(2, x+1):
            if x%value == 0:
                return False
```

This means value goes from `2` to `x` **included**. Which means that there will necessarily be `x%value == 0`. So your function **always** return False and then primes is a list of `0`.

You should use `for value in range(2, x)`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your is_prime function , you are looping from 2 to `x` inclusive of both  , so x%x is always  0 ,and hence it will always return False.

You just need to loop till the sqrt of the number.

Example code -

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    else:    
        for value in range(2, int(x**(1/2))+1):
            if x%value == 0:
                return False
        else: 
            return True
```

Also, in the other function you should start

Comment: This last else is not required and seems odd in python code

Comment: True, but thats not the actual issue, if we are fixing other non-essential issues there are tons of them to fix :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    else:
        if x == 2:
            return True
        for value in range(2, int(x**(0.5)) + 1):
            if x%value == 0:
                return False
        return True
def primes_in(x):
    primes = []
    for value in range(2, x+1):
        if is_prime(value) == True:
            primes.append(1)
        elif is_prime(value) == False:
            primes.append(0)
        else:
            primes.append(0)
    return sum(primes)
print primes_in(25)
```

Comment: This would not work, since if the number `x**(1/2)` can be `float`, and `float` and `float` does not work with `range` function